# nodeJS syntaxError: unexpected token this

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Background**: User inputs details about a flight in `app.js`, which then prints it out in the console. Only one module is used from `index.js`, which contains an object prototype.

**Problem**: When I run the command "node app.js", I get the following error:

```
/Users/
UserName/Desktop/NodeTrainingWork/04/objectcreat/flight/index.js:3
var this.data = {
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/UserName/Desktop/NodeTrainingWork/04/objectcreat/app.js:1:76)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
```

This is the `index.js` code:

```
var Flight = function() {

 var this.data = {
    number: null,
    origin: null,
    destination: null,
    arrivalTime: null
};

this.fill = function(info) {
    for (var prop in this.data) {
        if (this.data[prop] != 'undefined') {
            this.data[prop] = info[prop];
        }
    }
};

this.triggerArrival: function() {
    this.data.arrivalTime = Date.now();
    }

this.getInformation: function() {
    return this.data;
    }   
};      


module.exports = function(info) {
    var instance = new Flight();
    instance.fill(info);
    return instance;

};
```

And this is the code in the `app.js` file:

```
     var flight = require('./flight');


var pdxlax = {
    number: 847,
    origin: 'PDX',
    destination: 'LAX'
};

var pl = flight(pdxlax);
pl.triggerArrival();

console.log(pl.getInformation());


var pk340 = {
    number: 340,
    origin: 'ISL',
    destination: 'DXB'
};

var pk = flight(pk340);
pk.triggerArrival();

console.log(pk.getInformation());
```

I dont know where I am going wrong. From what I have learned, my way of creating a an object prototype is correct.

Comment: As an error says you have ` var this.data = {`. Using var here is an error, remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` is used to create a new variable, not to create a property on an object.

Remove `var` from the line that is erroring.